# How to use Nativescript preview for web app showing of my Vue project using qr code?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

How to use Nativescript to share preview of my web app made of Vue

Answer (score 0):

So make sure you have the playground app from appstore or google play (make sure it latest).  Now depending on the version you are currently using it may/may-not work.  If your project is pre 7 (6.5 etc).  It should work.  Nut if you are running the latest.. might have mixed results.  Usually depending on the number of plugins your using.

Assuming above... run tns preview ... or ns preview (version 7).Open the playground app and point at QR code